# Weird dropdown behavior css

Tags: html, css

I have two dropdown lists and they work as expected(that they show the content on hover) however, If I click on the area outside (left side) the list , the dropdown list still shows.

I have tried fixing the CSS but I have not been able to pin point the problem.

Is there a better approach for styling dropdown as I am still new to CSS.

UPDATE:

Testing this in firefox and I was unable to recreate the issue. How can I make sure that works consistently in all browsers?

```css
.dropbtn {
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 160px;
    margin-left: 276px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 900;
    background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 480px;
    height: 0px;
    background: antiquewhite;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    /* min-width: 160px; */
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    right: 5px;
    top: -20px;
    margin-left: 283px;
}

.sphere {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    /* position: relative; */
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 165px;
    margin-left: -55px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    table-layout: fixed;
    color: black;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 12px 16px 13px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: none;
    font-size: 21px;
}
.dropdown-content a:first-child {
  padding-top: 35px;
  background: url("Images/sidearrow.png") no-repeat 7px 36px;
}

.dropdown a {
 background:url("Images/sidearrow.png") no-repeat 7px;
}

.dropdown-content a:first-child:hover {
  padding-top: 35px;
  background: url("Images/sidewhite.png") no-repeat 3px 36px;
  color:black;
  background-color: rgb(255,131,0);
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background:url("Images/sidewhite.png") no-repeat 3px;
 background-color: rgb(255,131,0);
 color:white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

div#arrow {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}


/* SENTINAL */


.dropbtn-sentinal {
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 160px;
    margin-left: 276px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 900;
    background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-sentinal{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 480px;
    height: 0px;
    background: antiquewhite;
}

.dropdown-content-sentinal {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    /* min-width: 160px; */
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    right: 5px;
    top: -20px;
    margin-left: 283px;
}

.sphere-sentinal {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    /* position: relative; */
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 165px;
    margin-left: -55px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.dropdown-content-sentinal a {
    table-layout: fixed;
    color: black;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 12px 16px 13px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: none;
    font-size: 21px;
}
.dropdown-content-sentinal a:first-child {
  padding-top: 35px;
  background: url("Images/sidearrow.png") no-repeat 7px 36px;
}

.dropdown-sentinal a {
 background:url("Images/sidearrow.png") no-repeat 7px;
}

.dropdown-content-sentinal a:first-child:hover {
  padding-top: 35px;
  background: url("Images/sidewhite.png") no-repeat 3px 36px;
  color:black;
  background-color: rgb(255,131,0);
}

.dropdown-content-sentinal a:hover {
 background:url("Images/sidewhite.png") no-repeat 3px;
 background-color: rgb(255,131,0);
 color:white;
}

.dropdown-sentinal:hover .dropdown-content-sentinal {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-sentinal:hover .dropbtn-sentinal {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

div#arrow-sentinal {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}

div#dropdown-one {
    width: 500px;
    height: 198px;
}

div#dropdown-two {
    margin-left: 700px;
    margin-top: -198px;
}


div#dropdown-content a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid black 1px;
    display: table-caption;
    background-color: rgb(237,237,238);
    background: url(Images/sidearrow.png) no-repeat 7px 36px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdown.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="averios-header">
 <div id="averios-logo">
  <img src="averioslogo.png" width="176" height="129">
 </div>
 <div id="setting-dropdown">
  <!-- SETTING DROPDOWN WILL GO HERE -->
 </div>
 <div id="header-hr">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="log-in">
 <div id="loginHeader">
  <h1>Portal</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="welcome-text">
  <p> Welcome name </p>
  <p> Your last login was time on date </p>
  <br>
  <p> Please select an application below to begin </p>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="dropdown-one">
 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">SELECT</button>
   <div class="sphere">
  <div id="arrow">
   <img src="C:\Users\mseh\Desktop\Images\arrow.png" width="29" height="27" alt=""/>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-two">
 <div class="dropdown-sentinal">
   <button class="dropbtn-sentinal">SELECT</button>
   <div class="sphere-sentinal">
  <div id="arrow-sentinal">
   <img src="C:\Users\mseh\Desktop\Images\arrow.png" width="29" height="27" alt=""/>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown-content-sentinal">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a> 
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You have tested your own example, right? If I go outside the list, the list closes (as it should). So either the example doesn't give us the problem you're experiencing, or you are experiencing it, and that makes me question the browser you're using. Because the example above works as intended.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I just tested in firefox and it works without a problem. But the CSS wont load in firefox. Any suggestions related to how I can fix this?

Comment: Huh? I'm looking at your code - it shows a blue rectangle with half-circles on each side, and when I hover over it, it changes to green, and drops down a select-menu. This looks the same, and works the same in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and Opera. What in the world kind of browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome itself. I just reset the browser but the issue still remains in chrome. It could just be my browser.

Comment: Which version of Chrome? And what OS?

Comment: Version 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit) and windows platform

Comment: Ah, wait. I misunderstood you, I think. If you hover on the list-items, then the dropdown closes, but if you, on first hover on the "select-box" goes straight to the left, it stays open until you scroll the page, move the mouse over it again, etc?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Please check the image I added just now. If i dont hover over the select button, the list still shows where as I did not hover over the select button. Does that help ? The pointer here is where my mouse pointer is. It should not open the dropdown content when I am not hovering over the select button

Comment: Added an answer (had to modify the code a bit, so this is version 3 or something) - see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here - I shortened the example down a bit (I also don't think you need all that separate CSS for more than one button, you should be able to utilize the classes, and just change specifics by using `#dropdown_two .classname` for the things (like position) you might want to change.

The problem in Chrome, I think, was that the width of the container was wider than the button itself, and that made it misbehave. It might not be 100%, but it should get you started. I changed some values to dynamic (`em` instead of `px`) so there might be some issues.

```css
#dropdown-one {
  margin-left: 20em;
  }
.dropbtn {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
  height: 3.2em;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 900;
    background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 12.5em;
    background:antiquewhite;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    top: -20px;
}

.sphere {
    height: 2.9em;
    width: 2.9em;
    border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
    /* position: relative; */
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: .1em;
    z-index: 2;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    table-layout: fixed;
    color: black;
    padding: .75em;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: none;
    font-size: 21px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropdown-content a:first-child {
  padding-top: 35px;
  background: url("Images/sidearrow.png") no-repeat 7px 36px;
}

.dropdown a {
 background:url("Images/sidearrow.png") no-repeat 7px;
}

.dropdown-content a:first-child:hover {
  background: url("Images/sidewhite.png") no-repeat 3px 36px;
  color:black;
  background-color: rgb(255,131,0);
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background:url("Images/sidewhite.png") no-repeat 3px;
 background-color: rgb(255,131,0);
 color:white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

div#arrow {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="averios-header">
 <div id="setting-dropdown">
  <!-- SETTING DROPDOWN WILL GO HERE -->
 </div>
</div>

<div id="log-in">
 <div id="loginHeader">
  <h1>Portal</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="welcome-text">
  <p> Welcome name </p>
  <p> Your last login was time on date </p>
  <p> Please select an application below to begin </p>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="dropdown-one">
 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">SELECT</button>
   <div class="sphere">
  <div id="arrow">
   <img src="C:\Users\mseh\Desktop\Images\arrow.png" width="29" height="27" alt=""/>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ if you can help me with one thing, how can move the select button to right, if I move the button to the right it has the same behavior.

Comment: Stop moving the button, move the container for the button. I updated the answer.